# Unable to install packages due to /tmp at 100% usage

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, tmp

I'm not sure how this happened, but my /tmp directory is on a separate partition called "overflow" with only 1.1M allocated to it, which is 100%. This is preventing me from doing almost anything, including installing packages.

The server is Ubuntu 14.04 running on EC2. I recently increased the size of it's disk from 20G to 200G and rebooted the instance, and now `df -H` shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.1G  8.2k  2.1G   1% /dev
tmpfs           415M  390k  415M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      529G   39G  469G   8% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/shm
none            105M     0  105M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.1M  1.1M     0 100% /tmp
```

What is this "overflow" filesystem and how do I get /tmp off of it?

Comment: Please run `sudo du -hd1 /tmp | sort -h` and show the output, as well as the output of `mount | grep tmp` please.

Comment: If you've just moved to a 200G disk, I'm curious why / reports 529G. Do you know how to `fsck` your / disk?

Answer (score 2):

If your “/tmp” mount on a linux filesystem is mounted as overflow (often sized at 1MB), this is likely due to you not specifying “/tmp” as its own partition and your root filesystem filled up and “/tmp” was remounted as a fallback. To fix this after you’ve cleared space, just unmount the fallback and it should remount at its original point:

```
sudo umount overflow
```